# Flutter stream work in web version but not in android

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

anyone can help why this stream doesn`t have any return if i use flutter run for android, but work well when i used flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html.

```
Stream<List<types.Message>> getMessagesList(String roomid) {
  var db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('messages/$roomid');
  final snap = db.onValue;
  final drStream = snap.map((event) {
    final specMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as Map);
    final specList = specMap.entries.map((e) {
      return types.Message.fromJson(e.value as Map<String, dynamic>);
    }).toList();
    specList.sort(
      (a, b) {
        var adt = a.createdAt!;
        var bdt = b.createdAt!;
        return bdt.compareTo(adt);
      },
    );

    return specList;
  });
  return drStream;
}
```

I think the issue is map, but I can't figure out which part it is.

Comment: The code looks fine to me at first glance, but there are some unknown dependencies. Did you already debug the problem locally, stepping through toe code. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: i tried debug for sometimes first and try to find somewhere before come to this question,  the thing make me bit confuse is it work as expected in web version, and return coreect value, but when it comes to android debuging i still get e.value but no return value specList. is there any way to debug mapping? and why the value return as expeted in flutter run web version

Comment: Sure. If you set a breakpoint on every line, you'll also set one on `return types.Message.fromJson(e.value as Map<String, dynamic>);` and can inspect where `e.value` in there has the value you expect.